# Importing vue typescript type definitions

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I am trying to reference the typescript definitions for vue in my main file `entry.ts`.

Here is 'entry.ts' located at src/js/entry,ts,
the type definition for vue is located at src/js/lib/bower/vue/types/index.d.ts

```
/// <reference path='./lib/typings/jquery.d.ts' />
/// <reference path='./lib/bower/vue/types/index.d.ts' />

let data: Object = {},
    app: Vue = new Vue({
        data: data,
        el: '#app'
    });
console.log(app);

class Test {
    private id: string;
    constructor(id: string) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public getElement(): any {
        return $(this.id);
    }
}
console.log(new Test('asdf').getElement());
```

When this file gets compiled, the output is as follows.
BTW typescript is targeting es6 with es6 modules.

```
[steventheevil@Steven-PC webdev-starter]$ tsc
src/js/entry.ts(5,10): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Vue'.
src/js/entry.ts(5,20): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Vue'.
```

The JQuery works fine (it looks like), so I replace the reference to the vue type definition with an import.

```
/// <reference path='./lib/typings/jquery.d.ts' />
import * as Vue from './lib/bower/vue/types/index';

let data: Object = {},
    app: Vue = new Vue({
        data: data,
        el: '#app'
    });
console.log(app);

class Test {
    private id: string;
    constructor(id: string) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public getElement(): any {
        return $(this.id);
    }
}
console.log(new Test('asdf').getElement());
```

It compiles fine, here's the output:

```
import * as Vue from '../../src/js/lib/bower/vue/types/index';
let data = {}, app = new Vue({
    data: data,
    el: '#app'
});
console.log(app);
class Test {
    constructor(id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    getElement() {
        return $(this.id);
    }
}
console.log(new Test('asdf').getElement());
```

The problem is that the import statement for the type definition is not removed. This causes an error later when I use rollup with babel (I don't use the rollup plugin for ts because I need to manipulate the files between rollup and ts). How do I tell the typescript compiler to remove imports for type definitions (.d.ts files)?

Here's the type definition for vue (src/jslib/bower/vue/types/index.d.ts)

```
import * as V from "./vue";
import * as Options from "./options";
import * as Plugin from "./plugin";
import * as VNode from "./vnode";

// `Vue` in `export = Vue` must be a namespace
// All available types are exported via this namespace
declare namespace Vue {
  export type CreateElement = V.CreateElement;

  export type Component = Options.Component;
  export type AsyncComponent = Options.AsyncComponent;
  export type ComponentOptions<V extends Vue> = Options.ComponentOptions<V>;
  export type FunctionalComponentOptions = Options.FunctionalComponentOptions;
  export type RenderContext = Options.RenderContext;
  export type PropOptions = Options.PropOptions;
  export type ComputedOptions<V extends Vue> = Options.ComputedOptions<V>;
  export type WatchHandler<V extends Vue> = Options.WatchHandler<V>;
  export type WatchOptions = Options.WatchOptions;
  export type DirectiveFunction = Options.DirectiveFunction;
  export type DirectiveOptions = Options.DirectiveOptions;

  export type PluginFunction<T> = Plugin.PluginFunction<T>;
  export type PluginObject<T> = Plugin.PluginObject<T>;

  export type VNodeChildren = VNode.VNodeChildren;
  export type VNodeChildrenArrayContents = VNode.VNodeChildrenArrayContents;
  export type VNode = VNode.VNode;
  export type VNodeComponentOptions = VNode.VNodeComponentOptions;
  export type VNodeData = VNode.VNodeData;
  export type VNodeDirective = VNode.VNodeDirective;
}

// TS cannot merge imported class with namespace, declare a subclass to bypass
declare class Vue extends V.Vue {}

export = Vue;
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I think you need to explore @types

Comment: @Aniruddha Das Yes, I've looked at https://www.npmjs.com/~types, but I'm not using npm for managing web dependencies, I'm using bower.

Comment: @Aniruddha Das I've also looked at https://github.com/typings/typings, but it doesn't have type definitions for vue (at least not 2.0).

Comment: @Aniruddha Das update: I'm using typings now with the vue types installed via bower, but it still gives me the same error (I'm using reference).

Comment: can you give a plunkar

Comment: @Aniruddha Actually, I got it to work after reading the docs a few times. Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: @Aniruddha Das I don't know what a plunkar is, but if you would like to see how I did it, here it is: https://github.com/StevenTheEVILZ/webdev-starter

Comment: sure, I will have a look into that

Answer (score 4):

I stumbled upon this question when trying to figure out how to import `VNode` from my typescript code.

Perhaps my answer would help someone facing the same issue.

The type definitions are provided at `vue/types`. Import the required interfaces or classes from there.

Using `VNode` as example:

```
// main.ts
import Vue from 'vue';
import { VNode } from 'vue/types';
import App from './App.vue';

new Vue({
  render: (h): VNode => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

Vue version used: 2.6.10.